# modify json using form and PHP

Tags: php, json, forms

I'm developing a page that takes the info of a json, print a form with the json's values, the user can change it and now I'm trying to upload this data to override the original json with the new data. At this point, I have two arrays, one with the "keys" of the json, and another with the new data that must contain. I can't build the json in the correct way. The problem is to match the two propierties (key and data) to make an array for json_decode after.

I have:

`$arrayClave` with the keys of the json.
and `$guardar` with the new data.

I have to build a new json with the keys plus the data, like this:

`{"ID":"12450","MARCA":"Roly" .... }`

I've tried to build the array like `array($arrayClave[1] => $guardar[1]);`

but I need to build it for every number of inputs, that change in different cases, so I need to use a loop, but it's not possible to do something like:

```
for($i=0; $i<99; $i++){
    $var = $arrayClave[$i] => $guardar[$i],;
}

$result = array($var);
```

I know this is not correct, but I don't know the way to do it. If someone can help me I'll be gratefull, I hope I've explained myself in the best way :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where $arrayClave and $guardar should be arrays

```
 for($i=0; $i<99; $i++){
  $arrayClave[$i] = $guardar[$i];
  }

 print_r(json_encode($arrayClave));
```

try this

Comment: It returns syntax error, that's the problem I have with this solution. Thanks!

Comment: did you remember to remove the "," you have after `$guardar[$i]` in your original post?

Comment: You shouldn't have any arrows, use @KarthickKumarGanesh's solution, not your `$var = $arrayClave[$i] => $guardar[$i],;` solution

Comment: @ManelMusti can you give the full code ,so that i can check through

Comment: yes Jaime, I did, but it seems I can't use the "=>" without quotes, and with it doesn't give the result I'm looking for

Comment: Why do you need to use the `=>` at all?

Comment: Oh! I didn't see it well, I'm so sorry. Now it worked, thank you very much to everyone!

Comment: I'm new in php, I've read that it was de way to build an array to encode json, but I'm glad to see there are other ways. Thank you very much!

Comment: Anyway, now I have the values, but not the keys, I have in the json:

["222210","Dogo" .... ]

and I need:

["ID":"222210","MARCA":"DOGO" ... ]

Comment: post both of your arrays

Comment: I've posted it down in a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Array 1: The Array that containd the Keys "tags" of the json, it comes from the previous page, by a form input:

```
$arrayClave
```

Array2: The Array that contains the values of the json, it gets the value of each input that the user has modified in the previous page:

```
foreach ($arrayClave as $value){
    $valorA = ($_GET[$value]);
    $guardar[] = $valorA;
}
```